# Where can I find the django.contrib.admin tests?

Tags: django, admin, testing

I've written a custom admin filter, now I'm looking for tests of the builtin filterspecs...where can I find those? A

jmoritz@laptop:~/workspace/django/django$ grep -ir testcase . | grep -ir admin

returned only the admindocs tests...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The tests for the admin aren't in the 'django/' section of the tree; they're in the top-level 'tests/' section, along with most of the rest of the test suite shipped with Django.

As far as I know, though, filterspecs are a specific area which currently has no tests; there are some historical reasons for this, but if someone would like to buckle down and write them I'm pretty sure we'd accept :)

Answer (score 0):

there are some tests in the testfolder (for admin), but cannot find any testcase for the filterspecs:

jmoritz@laptop:~/workspace/django$ grep -ir filterspec tests/
jmoritz@laptop:~/workspace/django$